# Accessing all textbox id at once in cs file which are inside a datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datalist which has a placeholder and inside placeholder I have textboxes.I need to access those textbox.Sure i can do that but each one has to be accessed seperately.It will be long and tedious,i was thinking if there is a way to access all those textbox at once.

```
<asp:DataList ID="profileDl" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="findMYcontrol" >
<ItemTemplate>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12 plcontTop " >

<asp:Image ID="imgP" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("pp_path")%>' Height="115px" Width="150px" />
</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12" >

<asp:FileUpload ID="profileUP" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="imgbutt" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" OnClick="picClick" Text="Upload" />


<asp:PlaceHolder ID="profile_tb" runat="server">

<table class="tbl_ptb">
<tr>
<td><b> UserName: </b> </td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="tb_uname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/></td> 
</tr>

<tr>
<td><b> RealName: </b> </td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="tb_rname" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>'/></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b> Email: </b> </td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="tb_email" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("email")%>' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b> Address: </b> </td>
<td><asp:TextBox  ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("address")%>' /></td> 
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b> Sex: </b> </td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="tb_sex" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("sex")%>' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b> Account: </b> </td>
<td> <asp:TextBox ID="tb_acc" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("acType")%>'/></td>
</tr>
</table>

<asp:Button ID="editmyprofile" class="btn btn-danger btn-block editbutt" runat="server" OnClick="savemyP" Text="save" />
</asp:PlaceHolder>



</div>
</div>

</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I need to access all the textboxes inside placeholder `profile_tb` in the corresponding .cs file.

For now i have accessed the placeholder as

```
public void findMYcontrol(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        FileUpload fu = (FileUpload)e.Item.FindControl("profileUP");

        fileup = fu;

        PlaceHolder ph1 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("profile_lbl");
        ph_lbl = ph1;

        PlaceHolder ph2 = (PlaceHolder)e.Item.FindControl("profile_tb");
        ph_tb = ph2;


    }
}
```

And `ph_lbl and ph_tb` are used as page variable.Doing same thing solves the problem but it will be lengthy to access all those textbox id with this approach.
Is there a another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be like following:

1. Inside your placeholder, instead of **table** use **asp:table** and set an Id to it (the code behind **asp:table** is same as **table**).
2. In your .cs file, get the **asp:table** by its id using **FindControl** method.
3. With table in hand, you can access all of its columns and cells in a for loop

Hope this help

**Edited**

for on the table would be like following:

```
foreach(TableRow tr in tableId.Rows)
{
    //if your textbox is in an known cell, instead of this for loop you can
    //get it by its index like tr.Cells[i]
    foreach (TableCell tc in tr.Cells)
    {
        foreach (Control con in tc.Controls)
        {
            //check if con is of type textBox and get its text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Um help me with for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like below

```
IEnumerable<Control> EnumerateControlsRecursive(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
         yield return child;
         foreach (Control descendant in EnumerateControlsRecursive(child))
             yield return descendant;
     }
}
```

It will iterate and return all the controls inside any container and then you can use like below

```
foreach (Control c in EnumerateControlsRecursive(yourcontainerId))
{
      if(c is TextBox)
      {
          // do something useful
      }
}
```